# Java/Grails - unmarshalling UTF-8 encoded cyrillic characters

Tags: java, xml, grails, utf-8, jaxb

I'm having problems with encoded cyrillic characters in a XML file that I'm trying to unmarshall into jaxb models. The characters have been hex-encoded so that they show up in the xml like this:

```
&#x412; &#x446; ...
```

However, when I try to unmarshall the XML file, I'd presume they would show up in the final outcome as original cyrillic characters, but no matter how I do the unmarshalling, they finally end up showing in the jaxb model String variable in the encoded format: `&#x412; &#x446; ...`

I ensured that the XML itself is fine by running it through online decoder in UTF-8 mode and it managed to interpret the encoded characters in cyrillic format just fine.

The latest try I did with the unmarshalling is sort of over the top enforced UTF-8:

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance("path.to.the.jaxb.model").createUnmarshaller()
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(xmlFile.inputStream,"UTF-8")
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
JAXBElement<SiteDataExportType> element
try {
    element = (JAXBElement<SiteDataExportType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is)
} finally {
    reader.close()
}
```

But after this code when I look at the outcome, the String value for that XML node still shows itself as `&#x412; &#x446; ...` instead of 'В ц ...'

Any ideas, how should I go about this to get the cyrillic characters as they are instead of the encoded format?

Comment: I've just read a file containing the characters with DOM and it read the cyrillic characters just fine!

Comment: Indeed, the encoded format itself should be correct - what I am wondering is why the unmarshalling process doesn't realize this / do the decoding... When I look at the node's String value via the element variable, I still see them in the encoded format.